# Generic keyboard maps Ctrl, Win, Alt, AltGr to Shift

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-gnome

Both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd> are all mapped to <kbd>Shift</kbd> on a generic keyboard I'm using. Menu key is working. I tried with a Logitech one and all the keys work as intended. How can I fix the generic keyboard's mapping? I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS.

edit: I've tried with the `XKBMODEL`s `pc105` and `SKIP`, to no avail.

Comment: It said `SKIP`. I changed it to `pc105`, but that didn't help. A terminal on that folder said `** (gedit:24533): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported`, among other things.

Comment: I've rebooted, and `XKBMODEL` is now `pc105`, but the problem persists.